# Add the Entry in table

Tags: mysql, sql

Please refer the following table

```
PID     Amount  Qty 

101     85.00   4
7078    971.25  5
7173    115.50  6
```

Using above table need to add the entry in new table like below

```
PID     Amount  Qty 

101     85.00   4
101     971.25  5
101     115.50  6
7078    85.00   4
7078    971.25  5
7078    115.50  6
7173    85.00   4
7173    971.25  5
7173    115.50  6
```

Suggest the sql query for this entry

Comment: What a strange requirement.

Comment: you can corner this niche market, peddling it about, bringing potential competitors to their knees

Answer (score 1):

**Create Tables:**

```
create table mytable(PID int,  Amount decimal(5,2), Qty int);

insert into mytable values
(101 ,85.00  ,4),
(7078,971.25 ,5),
(7173,115.50 ,6);

create table secondtable(PID int,  Amount decimal(5,2), Qty int);
```

Using `Cross Join`, you could do write an insert query like this:

```
insert into secondtable
select m.pid,
       m1.amount,
       m1.qty
from mytable m
cross join mytable m1;
```

**Select Statement:**

```
select * from secondtable
order by pid,qty;
```

**Result:**

```
+------+--------+-----+
| PID  | Amount | Qty |
+------+--------+-----+
|  101 | 85     |   4 |
|  101 | 971.25 |   5 |
|  101 | 115.5  |   6 |
| 7078 | 85     |   4 |
| 7078 | 971.25 |   5 |
| 7078 | 115.5  |   6 |
| 7173 | 85     |   4 |
| 7173 | 971.25 |   5 |
| 7173 | 115.5  |   6 |
+------+--------+-----+
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab9a4/1/0)